# Converting a C# SQL string into a SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my C# code I have the following piece of code that I am looking at converting into SQL in a stored procedure:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE 1 = 1");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xzone))
{
    sql.AppendFormat(" AND xzone LIKE '{0}%'", xzone);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(yregion))
{
    sql.AppendFormat(" AND yregion LIKE '{0}%'", yregion);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zzone))
{
    sql.AppendFormat(" AND zzone LIKE '{0}%'", zzone);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
{
    sql.AppendFormat(" AND region LIKE '{0}%'", region);
}
```

What I am trying to do is find a clean, easier way to make these "and" conditionals in C# fit into a SQL procedure without having to make 16 long difficult to read if and if else's or a large amount of CASE statements to cover every single combination.

Maybe I am a victim of wishful thinking here, but I thought maybe I am missing something that would simplify this conversion. Thanks !

Comment: Be aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL inyection.

Comment: Annoyingly, the SQL language (nor any of its main implementations) doesn't have any way to add conditional clauses to `WHERE` statements (or parameterize database object identifiers) - which is why Dynamic SQL exists, unfortunately. In the .NET world people use Linq for this to avoid having to use Dynamic SQL directly.

Comment: BTW, don't fall for the trap of doing `WHERE ( @param1 IS NULL OR col LIKE @param1 )` because it breaks the query optimizer (surprisingly even today, SQL Server doesn't elide all conditions it knows will be false).

Comment: @Dai True, but only relevant if the column in question is indexed. Without an index, performance is the same. And for small tables, the difference may be small enough to be irrelevant.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution might be to use `CASE WHEN ELSE` in the `WHERE` clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1 (
    @xzone varchar(50),
    @yregion varchar(50),
    ... 
)
AS
BEGIN
   select *
   from MyDatabase
   where 
       xzone like '%' + case when @xzone is null then '' else @xzone end +'%'
   and 
       yregion like '%' + case when @yregion is null then '' else @yregion end +'%'
   and
       ...
END
```

This is not very sufficient on large tables but does what you need in just one query.

To call the procedure, use

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Proc1", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@xzone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ...;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@yregion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ...; 
      ...
      con.Open();
      SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      ...
    }
  }
```

To assign db NULL you can do

```
=(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? (object)DBNull.Value : s);
=(object)s ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Very nice how you did the + case ! Thanks . I know it is not very efficient but the table I am working against is not terribly large. !

Comment: "case when" is useful when the seach keyword needs to be manupulated, alternatively its "short" version with IsNull() can be `xzone like '%' + ISNULL(@xzone,'') +'%'`